# AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, pandas

I am having Time Series data in my dataframe (dataset) after indexing by date when i am trying to call any value by date am getting an error of AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Can please help me.

Please follow the screenshot for code:
[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtwS.png)
[Figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX96H.png)

Comment: The screenshot doesn't contain any error messages though. Please post code as `formatted text`, _not_ images

Comment: Have you tried `df.loc['2020-07-06']`?

Comment: Thank you very much sir it work